# Propability - waiting for the train

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Train leaves station regularly every 10 minutes, what is the probability that I will wait more than three minutes, if I come to the station at random?

$$\exp(10)$$
$$P(X>3) = 1 - P(x<3)$$
$$1-(1-e^{-10*3})$$

But i don't think that it is good, I am no sure if it is exponential probability function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrival time has a uniform distribution $U(0,10)$ over the interval between the previous and next trains. So the probability that you wait more than 3 minutes is $7/10$